# VB.NET - Select text until certain character

Tags: .net, vb.net

The title may not be precise but I couldn't think if a better way of explaining it.

I am working on a project for a client which utilizes HTML source code from a number of different websites.

At the moment, the source is displayed but I need to be able to pick the first URL out of the source and then display it on a `Label`.

My problem being. VB text boxes don't display hyper links and (as far as I know) don't have any tools to pick a hyperlink out of a string.

I need to be able to get the first hyperlink from a multiline text box. The link can often be very long and typically does not end with a .com or .net or what ever, it's just a domain then a long combination of numbers and letters. I need to be able to extract this URL. It is encased inside a HTML frame and the link will change based on what website it visits obviously so I think the thing I'm really looking for is a way to extract that HTML frame with the link inside it then removing the excess HTML to be left with the raw link.

I have tried to explain this as best I could; let me know if you need some clarification.

Comment: So you need to extract links from strings using Regex, is that it?

Comment: You can probably get away with using regular expressions for this simple case but you ought to check out the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/‎).

Comment: @canon: The question doesn't make quite clear whether HTML source code is to be acknowledged. In particular, *the first URL out of the source* could well include purely textual, non-linked URLs (as they sometimes appear in forums that disallow links).

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is a unclear but you can pretty much use HtmlAgilityPack or just use Regex [Regular Expressions] in order to return what you want from a page

**Example**

```
' The input string.
Dim value As String = "/content/alternate-1.aspx"

' Invoke the Match method.
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(value, _
                 "content/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.aspx$", _
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

' If successful, write the group.
If (m.Success) Then
    Dim key As String = m.Groups(1).Value
    Console.WriteLine(key)
End If
```